# out = [item for t in lt for item in t] how this will get executed

Tags: python

`out = [item for t in lt for item in t]`, how this loop will get executed, please elaborate this  as I am a beginner in python so I am having difficulty to understand this concept

```
 lt = [('Geeks', 2), ('For', 4), ('geek', '6')] 

 out = [item for t in lt for item in t] 

 print(out)
```

Comment: It will print eash every element in single list. Basically this is flattening list of tuple to list

Comment: It is called [List Comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It provides concise way to create lists.

Comment: if you are comfortable with list comprehensions, the only additional step is knowing that the "for x in y for item in x" read from left to right, outer to inner. If you're not familiar with list comprehensions, you may want to read a tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

Your list comprehension will be executed as:

```
out = []
for t in lt:
    for item in t:
        out.append(item)
```

The result will be a flattened list.

Notice that the left-to-right order of the `for` loops in the list comprehension is the same as the outer-to-inner order of the `for` loops in the expanded version.

Answer (score 1):

```
   lst =  [item for t in lt for item in t]
```

The above code is similar to the below one,

```
lst = []
for t in lt:
    for item in t:
        lst.append(item)
```

**List comprehension:**

> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. It consists
>   of brackets containing an expression followed by a for clause, then
>   zero or more for or if clauses. The expressions can be anything,
>   meaning you can put in all kinds of objects in lists.

Answer (score 1):

```
lt = [('Geeks', 2), ('For', 4), ('geek', '6')]
out = [item for t in lt for item in t]
print(out)
```

in code you have Double Iteration in List Comprehension and it is equivalent to:

```
out = []
for t in lt:
    for item in t:
        out.append(item)
print(out)
```

> **List Comprehensions**
>
> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists.
>
> It consists of brackets containing an expression followed by a for
>   clause, then zero or more for or if clauses. The expressions can be
>   anything, meaning you can put in all kinds of objects in lists.
>
> The result will be a new list resulting from evaluating the expression
>   in the context of the for and if clauses which follow it.
>
> *Syntax*
>
> The list comprehension starts with a `'['` and `']'`, to help you
>   remember that the result is going to be a list.
>
> The basic syntax is:
>
> ```
> [ expression for item in list if conditional ]
> ```
>
> This is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> for item in list:
>     if conditional:
>         expression
> ```
>
> Let's break this down and see what it does
>
> ```
> new_list = [expression(i) for i in old_list if filter(i)]
> ```
>
> `new_list`    : The new list (result).
>
> `expression(i)`: Expression is based on the variable used for each
>   element in the old list.
>
> `for i in old_lis`t: The word for followed by the variable name to
>   use, followed by the word in the old list.
>
> `if filter(i)`: Apply a filter with an If-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go step by step by order of the process:

- It will first iterate through the list called `lt`
- Then, iterate through the `t` which is every value in `lt`, it's a nested loop right now,

  `[('Geeks', 2), ('For', 4), ('geek', '6')]`

  ```
         t             t            t

    item   item   item   item  item   item
  ```
- And then, we finally at the end return every `item`, which results into 6 elements in the list.